# Show that $f(x)$ has an infinity of points of discontinuity in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{n} & \text { if } x \in\left(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right] \\
0 & \text { if } x=0
\end{array}\right.$
Show that $f(x)$ has a infinity of discontinuous points in $[0,1]$

I was trying

$ \lim_{x\to\frac{1^-}{n}} f(x)= \frac{1}{n} \neq \lim_{x\to\frac{1^+}{n}} f(x)= \frac{1}{n+1} $ so, $f(x)$ doesn't have limit in  $\frac{1}{n}$ so its discontinuous is a infinity of point of the form $\frac{1}{n}$

Is this right? and how can I show that is Riemann integrable in $[0,1]$?

Comment: What is your definition of the Riemann integral? That will tell you what you need to do.

Comment: f is Riemman Integrable if  $U_{f, P_{n}}-L_{f, P_{n}}<\epsilon$

Comment: Minor point, but I think you need to double check $\lim_{x\to\frac{1}{n}^+} f(x)$

Comment: @Joe it will be $\frac{1}{n-1}$ right?

Comment: Do you see that $f$ is increasing on $[0,1]$? And then monotone functions are Riemann integrable.

Comment: Yes, $\frac{1}{n-1}$

Comment: Integrability of monotone functions can always be established by choosing uniform partitions. Choose a partition $P$ of $[0,1]$ into $m$ subintervals of equal length and choose $m$ suitably for the given $\epsilon $.

Comment: Also, you could partition $[0,1]$ at $1/n$ for $n=1,\dots,k$, and show that the difference between the upper & lower Darboux sums on that partition is $\le 1/k$